# Get specific user information in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

i need some help, i've extended the custom user model but for some reason if in a template i get the needed field it doesn't show up anything.

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    utente = User.objects.filter(username__in=["user"])
    return render(request,"blog/index.html", {'users' : utente})
```

html:

```
{% for utente in users %}

                    <img class="img-circle center-block" src="{{ utente.img.url }}" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2 class="text-center">{{ utente.get_full_name }}</h2>
                    <p class="text-center">{{ utente.bio }}</p>

                {% endfor %}
```

With this code i can only get the name with the "get_full_name".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the custom model you made?

Comment: Just a heads-up, you do realize you're fetching users with the username `user`, right? Just wondering, because that usually doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah, i know, i wrote user because i wanted to hide the usernames :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are importing the Django provided user model not your custom user model.

Try changing:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

To

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

Then select your users using get_user_model

```
def index(request):
    utente = get_user_model().objects.filter(username__in=["user"])
    return render(request,"blog/index.html", {'users' : utente})
```

Also, make sure that AUTH_USER_MODEL is set to your custom user model in your settings.py file.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```